# In a $C^*$ algebra why $\|a\|\not =\rho(a)$ for any $a$?

Tags: c-star-algebras

In a $C^*$ algebra why $\|a\|\not =\rho(a)$ for any $a$? Where $\rho(a)$ is the spectral radius.

It can be shown that the equality holds for self-adjoint elements. Then that can be used to show that the Gelfand transform is an isometry. Thus $\|a\|=\|\hat{a}\|=max \{|\phi(a)| \hspace{0.2cm}| \phi\in Spec(A)
\}$. First equality follows from the Gelfand transformation being an isometry. The second follows form the definition of the norm on $C(Spec(A))$. But we know that $spec(a)=\{\phi(a) \hspace{0.2cm}| \phi\in Spec(A)
\}$. thus $\rho(a)=\rho(\hat{a})$ and the result follows. My professor said this is incorrect. What I am doing wrong here?

Edit:

I am assuming the algebra is commutative

Comment: There certainly are C* algebras where $\|a\| = \rho(a)$ for all $a$ (e.g. continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space).  On the other hand, there are $2 \times 2$ matrices with $\rho(a) = 0$ and $\|a\| \ne 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I understand I am wrong. But where does my reasoning fail? ( I am assuming $C^*$ algebra is commutative btw)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Also any commutative $C^*$ algebra is * isometrically isomorphic to a $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, namely $X= Spec(A)$

Comment: It is true for *commutative* C*-algebras.

Comment: On a commutative C* algebra, we do have $\|a\| = \rho(a)$.

Comment: You are also assuming that the C*-algebra is unital.

Comment: Ohhh, that clears everything up. Thank you very much everyone. Someone can post an answer or i can just close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is correct and your professor is wrong.

A faster proof is using the full power of Gelfand transformation. Indeed, without loss of generality we may assume that $A= C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Then if $f \in C(X)$, then $\operatorname{spec}(f) = f(X)$ and thus
$$\rho(f) =\max_x |f(x)|  = \|f\|_\infty.$$

For non-commutative $C^*$-algebras, the statement is false. Consider
$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{C}).$$
Then $A^2=0$ and thus $\operatorname{spec}(A) = \{0\}$ but $\|A \| \neq 0$.

Comment: I think I miscommunicated with him, just as I did just now. I assumed the algebra is commutative, which is the key assumption.  I think he thought i mean it is true for any $C*$ algebra which is false.

Comment: @Sorfosh Yes that's right. For your convenience, I added some details to my answer.